# What are the NettyNioAsyncHttpClient default configuration values?

Tags: amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-sdk-java-2.0

The AWS SDK netty HTTP client is configurable through `NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.Builder`, but I can't find any documentation on the default values.
In particular I'm using the firehose SDK and looking for the default `maxConcurrency` value.

Where can I find documentation for these defaults?

I read through the source code looking for defaults. It looks like the default builder works with an `AttributeMap` which is simply empty when configuration values are not set manually.